# With Angular module federation, how can I configure my shell and child apps to use different versions of the same library?

Tags: angular-module, angular14, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I'm using Angular 14 and module federation.  In my shell application, I'm using this library

```
"my-common-lib": "^0.0.10",
```

I load a child application using this in my routes

```
  {
    path: 'products',
    loadChildren: () =>
        loadRemoteModule({
            type: 'module',
            remoteEntry: 'http://localhost:8085/remoteEntry.js',
            exposedModule: './start'
        })
        .then(m => m.MyProductsModule)
  },
```

but I'm getting this error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unsatisfied version 0.0.10 from parentApp of shared singleton module my-common-lib (required =0.0.15)
```

probably because in my child application, I have this version of the shared library

```
"my-common-lib": "^0.0.15",
```

and this is my webpack.config.js file from my child app

```
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  name: 'customer',
  
  exposes: {
    './start':'./src/app/myProducts/myProducts.module.ts'
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

});
```

Is there a way to have each use their own version of the library?  I basically would like to isolate the child functinality from the parent but not sure how to do it or if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({

  name: 'customer',
  
  exposes: {
    './start':'./src/app/myProducts/myProducts.module.ts'
  },

  shared: {
    'my-common-lib-custom': {
      singleton: true,
      strictVersion: true,
      requiredVersion: '^0.0.15'
    },
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

});
```

```
import { myCommonLibCustom as myCommonLib } from 'my-common-lib-custom';
```

if not working try to use the shareScope option. This option creates a new namespace for shared modules